# Laravel 5.3, using api.example.com to example.com/api

Tags: api, laravel, nginx, routes

How to route api.example.com to example.com/api so i can just

```
api.example.com/v1/users
```

than using

```
example.com/api/v1/users.
```

I'm using nginx, thank you.

Comment: Put `rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ http://api.example.com/$1 redirect;` inside your server block for *example.com*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure these 2 steps are in place.

Check your nginx configuration `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf` and include the domain in the `server_name` like so:

```
server_name example.com api.example.com;
```

Check that you have a route setup within the `routes/api.php` file. Using the sub-domain group is optional but be sure that you have the correct routes.

**Example of using domain group:**

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.example.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/v1/users', ['as' => 'api.users.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
}
```

**Example without use of domain group** and allowing for both URL to point to the same Controller (be sure to define its own route names as per the `'as'`).

```
Route::get('/v1/users', ['as' => 'api.users.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
Route::get('/api/v1/users', ['as' => 'users.index', 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
```

**Update**:

Refer to official Laravel 5.3 documentation regarding the use of sub-domain routes https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: thanks for the help, 
now my nginx has direct the example and api.example to laravel public folder.

and for the route, since 5.3 has place the route at routes/web.php and routes/api.php, i must use the web.php to make it works.

Comment: Ah.. updated my answer. Didn't realise a change in the routes file structure.

Comment: need to use web.php with your solution since api.php can only accessed from example.com/api . you can try it.